# how to draw a rectangle with diagonals and axes of symmetry in c ++ in the console?

Tags: c++, console, draw

I would like to draw a rectangle with * in consol. Now I have code which draw circumference of a rectangle and its axes of symmetry, but I don't know how to draw diagonals. Can you help me? This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int s,d;
    printf ("the length of the rectangle \n");
    scanf ("%d",&s);
    printf ("width of the rectangle \n ");
    scanf ("%d",&d);
    int l;
    int p;
    int przekatna; 

    for (p=1; p<=s; p++)
    {
    printf ("\n");
    for (l=1;l<=d; l++)
    {

    if(p==1 || l==1 || l==d || s==p || p==((d+1)/2)  ) printf("*"); else printf(" ");
    if ( l==(d)/2 && p!=((d+1)/2) && p!=1 && p!=s) 
    printf("*"); else printf(""); 


    }
}
     return 0;
}
```

Edit, its good code, its working my teacher explained to me how to make diagonals and that's what it is

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int l;
    int p;
    int s;
    int d;
    printf ("the length of the rectangle  \n");
    scanf ("%d",&s);
    printf ("width of the rectangle  \n ");
    scanf ("%d",&d);

    for (p=1; p<=s; p++)
    {
    printf ("\n");
    for (l=1;l<=d; l++)

    {

    if(p==1 || l==1 || l==d || s==p 
    || p==s/2 || l==l/2 ||
     l==p*round(d/s) || l==(s+1-p)*round(d/s) )

    printf("*"); else printf(" ");


    }
  }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas?  Any attempts that failed? Could you do it if it was a square instead of a rectangle?

Comment: You *may* be looking for [ncurses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I strongly suspect this is from an introductory course in c/c++. ncurses  would be out of reach.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe - Maybe. But if that is the case then OP should have said as much in the question.

Comment: `#include <iostream>` means this is not C code, but if C++ you should be using `cin` and `cout`. Is your teacher teaching the fantasy language "C/C++"?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Should would could, it is the luxury of us experts to be able to extrapolate from incomplete data. https://www.thinkgeek.com/product/15cc/

Comment: `if(p==1 || l==1 || l==d || s==p || p==((d+1)/2)  ) printf("*"); else printf(" ");
    if ( l==(d)/2 && p!=((d+1)/2) && p!=1 && p!=s) 
    printf("*"); else printf("");` whenever you write (or copy-paste) an incomprehensible block of gunk like that, you need to be asking yourself "am I doing this wrong?" (Yes) and then you need to start re-writing the code using some intermediate variables with meaningful names (don't worry, the compiler will optimize them away) - and use newlines and spaces, please. Your future self will thank me/you. Don't write unreadable crap like that.

Comment: @Kapitan you're right, this is a school programming course.

Comment: @wiatrowskaz thanks, i forgot delete when i start new project on program.

Comment: @Jasper thank you for the advice, I will try to write a more readable code

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It's not helpful to shove multiple lines of code into a comment. Just write an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum feel free to be inspired by my "lines of code in a comment" and write an answer. *I* can't personally be bothered to do so.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: But you have written one, you just put it in a comment. Anyway, I actually have answered...

Comment: @einpoklum whatever.. just doing this for fun and giggles - not like I actually care much.

Comment: @einpoklum Put it in an answer (to be downvoted to hell), Happy now?

Answer (score 4):

That is actually not a trivial problem at all!

You see, the diagonals (when we imagine them to be lines of the same width as the circumference lines) don't correspond well to integer coordinates. So if you use `'*'` characters, either you'll have too many - several per one line - or too few, with breaks in the line.

You probably want to use [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for this problem.

Or - if you want to be simplistic, and place one `'*'` per line, use the formula for the diagonal, with rounding, to pick the best value irrespective of other lines:

> major_diagonal_y = (x - start_x) * ((float) rectangle_y_dim) / rectangle_x_dim

(assuming x is the vertical dimension and y is the horizontal one; you used other symbols but I found them a bit confusing.)

For the opposite (minor) diagonal, use

> minor_diagonal_y = rectangle_y_dim - major_diagonal_y

If you're willing to use other characters, you could consult [this tutorial on ASCII art](https://www.ludd.ltu.se/~vk/pics/ascii/junkyard/techstuff/tutorials/Hayley_Wakenshaw.html), with a section on diagonals. It demonstrates how to vary the use of characters to effectively have "sub-character" resolution. Quoting their example:

```
       /         .'               _,-'                            __
      /        .'             _,-'                        __..--''
     /       .'           _,-'                      __..''
    /      .'         _,-'                  __..--''
   /     .'       _,-'              __..--''
  /    .'     _,-'          __..--''                   ____....----"""
 /   .'   _,-'      __..--''           ____....----""""
/  .'  ,-'  __..--''   ____....----""""
```

Comment: @pakson: Your code has an outer loop for rows (x dimension in my answer) and an inner loop for columns (y dimension in my answer). You can check if a given character matches the formula, so yes, your code is quite adaptable to use the formula.

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation of how to solve my problem, I will check it in a moment but I wonder if it will be compatible with my code. Now my code does not work perfectly, the first conditional statement, if the drawing circuit and one symmetry axis, the second if I draw the second axis of symmetry, but in the console I see that https://i.imgur.com/rXjU4s8.png
the line on the right is distant, I think it's the fault of the loop that adds the second axis of symetri